# Qatar Airlines: Modifying Seat Selection

Tags: bookings, airlines, seating, qatar-airways, qatar

I've booked a ticket on Qatar Airlines. I can see on their website that there should be options for modifying seat selection. However, in "manage booking" page, I don't see any option for modifying seat selection. Could you let me know if I'm missing anything in the manage booking page? Where can I find the modify seat selection option?

For reference I'm attaching a screenshot of the manage booking settings options:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct that the Qatar Airways website [explains](https://qatarairways.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/206459388-Can-I-change-my-seat-and-meal-preferences-at-a-later-stage-) you can change your seat at "a later stage" from the "Manage Flight" menu you have highlighted.

However, when flying Economy Class, Qatar Airways only allows a seat selection at the "Convenience" or "Comfort" levels, not the entry-level "Classic" price tier. If you booked a "Classic" tier flight, there is no seat selection option available.

Comment: Yeah. You are right.
Their website doesn't have complete information.